# Phonegap Index redirect to login if not logged in

Tags: javascript, android, cordova, phonegap

So i have this javascript on myapp.js related to the index page:

```
myApp.onPageBeforeInit('index', function (page) {
        if (localStorage.login == 'true') {
          console.log('logged');
        }
        else if (localStorage.login == 'false') {
          console.log('not logged in')
          mainView.router.loadPage({
            url: 'login.html',
            ignoreCache: true,
            reload: false});
        }
    }).trigger();
```

What this does, is every time I go to the index page, if I'm not logged in, it sends me to the login.

The problem is, I'm using `pushState: true` so the android back button works.
But when I'm redirected to the login page, if I press the back button, I go again to the index page and it doesn't redirect me anymore even if I'm not logged because the page is already initiated before and is not initiated again… how can I fix this?

A fix would be to force pushState to always reload the previous page when going back… but I have no idea how to do that.

Any help?

Comment: you can try to add the same 'is logged' test in another event such as 'onPageBeforeAnimation' or 'onPageBack' (or also prevent the state to be pushed to history if in index and not logged)

Comment: You mean do the same with onPageBeforeAnimation and onPageBack with the index page too? I dont think it will work... because when i press the back button, it just goes back in the history, and the view changes to the last one, but i dont think any code is executed.

Comment: in theory, `onPageBeforeAnimation` is executed before the transition to another page (you should test the destination page instead of current one), and `onPageBack` when you press the back button (still have to find how to get the destination page), i don't see any reason why these wouldn't fire